# Specifiying between non default properties with Select-Object

Tags: powershell, select-object

I am practicing Powershell and the question that I have been assigned is as follows:

*Write a pipeline to get-process where cpu utilization is greater than zero, return properties not shown in default view and sort the results by CPU descending*

Currently I think I have completed everything except for the requirement of non default properties, which I assume can be done by the Select-Object cmdlet.

Code I have so far:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.CPU -gt 0 } | Select-Object -Property * | sort -Descending
```

I know the asterisks is a moniker for selecting all properties but I don't know how to set up a Boolean check for if the property is in the default view or not. Can someone please help me?

Comment: It might be a question of interpretation of the wording. It could be interpreted that returning properties shown in the default view, *plus* the extra ones not shown is what's required. Have a look at `Get-Process | Get-Member` to see if there's anything about the properties that flags them as default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `-ExcludeProperty` option in Select-Object:

```
Get-Process | `
Where-Object {$_.CPU -gt 0 } | `
Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty $(Get-Process)[0].PSStandardMembers.DefaultDisplayPropertySet.ReferencedPropertyNames | `
sort -Descending | format-table
```

Where:

```
$(Get-Process)[0].PSStandardMembers.DefaultDisplayPropertySet).ReferencedPropertyNames
```

is the default list for the first returned value in the `Get-Process` output. Breaking the whole thing down:

```
# First process
$fp = $(Get-Process)[0]
# Standard Members
$PSS = $fp.PSStandardMembers
# Default Display Property Set
$DDPS = $PSS.DefaultDisplayPropertySet
# Names of those properties in a list, that you can pass to -ExcludeProperty
$Excl = $DDPS.ReferencedPropertyNames
$Excl

# Command using variables
Get-Process | `
Where-Object {$_.CPU -gt 0 } | `
Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty $Excl | `
sort -Descending | format-table
```